# Failed to pass an input variable to my query

Tags: php, variables

I am  creating a phonebook program, where I can register and create my own contact list. After login, the page will be directed to the `tabmain` page where I can view, add, edit or delete contact, in a multitab form.

Here's the problem: Whenever I click the save button (the button in function `displayNew`), it should be getting the first name and surname then, look for the database if there is a match. If not, then add it should them. Now, what happens is, after I click the save button, nothing is passed to the variable.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<title>Tab-View Sample</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords"    content="" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_collect/distribution/tab-view.css" />

</head>
<body>

<?php $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 1; ?>
<?php
    include 'conSql.php';
    session_start();
    $mySession = $_SESSION['user'];

    //displays firsname and lastname of the user
    $getNames = getNames($mySession);
    $gET = explode("^", $getNames);

    echo "Hi, "."<b>". $gET[0] ." ". $gET[1] ."</b>"."!";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</br>";


?>

    <div class="TabView" id="TabView">


    <!-- ***** Tabs ************************************************************ -->

    <div class="Tabs" style="width: 452px;">
      <a <?=($id == 1) ? 'class="Current"' : 'href="sample.php?id=1"';?>>Contact List</a> 
      <a <?=($id == 2) ? 'class="Current"' : 'href="sample.php?id=2"';?>>Add contact</a>
      <a <?=($id == 3) ? 'class="Current"' : 'href="sample.php?id=3"';?>>Edit / Delete</a>
    </div>


    <!-- ***** Pages *********************************************************** -->

    <div class="Pages" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;">

      <div class="Page" style="display: <?=($id == 1) ? 'block' : 'none';?>"><div class="Pad"></div>

            list of query

      </div>
      <div class="Page" style="display: <?=($id == 2) ? 'block' : 'none';?>"><div class="Pad"></div>
            <Form Name ='' Method ='GET' action = 'tabmenu.php'>
            <?php 
                displayNew(); 
                if(isset($_GET['btnAdd'])){
                    $fname = $_GET['txtFname'];
                    $lname = $_GET['txtLname'];

                    // $s = "SELECT * ";
                    // $s .="FROM tbl_contactlist ";
                    // $s .="WHERE fname = '". $_GET['txtFname'] ."' and lname = '". $_GET['txtLname'] ."'";
                    echo $s;
                }

            ?>

      </div>
      <div class="Page" style="display: <?=($id == 3) ? 'block' : 'none';?>"><div class="Pad"></div>
            <?php 
                displayEdit(); 
            ?>  
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="css_collect/distribution/tab-view.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    tabview_initialize('TabView');
    </script>



    <?php


    function getNames($mySession){
    //get the real name of the user (firstname and lastname)
        $s = "SELECT * ";
        $s .="FROM tbl_users ";
        $s .="WHERE username = '". $mySession ."' ";        
        $rc = mysql_query($s);

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rc) or die();
        $details =  $row["fname"]."^".$row["lname"];
        return $details;
    }
    function displayNew(){
        echo "<table border = '0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><b>New Contact</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'>Please fill up the fields.</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>First Name: </td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtFname' id='txtFname'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Last Name: </td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtLname' id='txtLname'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Nick Name: </td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtNicname' id='txtNicname'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Contact Number: </td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtContactNum' id='txtContactNum'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='btnAdd' id='btnAdd' value='SAVE'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
    function displayEdit(){
        echo "<table border = '0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'><b>Edit / Delete Page</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='2'>You can edit or delete:</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>First Name: </td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtFname' id='txtFname'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Last Name: </td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtLname' id='txtLname'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Nick Name: </td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtNicname' id='txtNicname'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Contact Number: </td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='txtContactNum' id='txtContactNum'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='btnEdit' id='btnEdit' value='EDIT'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='btnDelete' id='btnDelete' value='DELETE'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='btnCancel' id='btnCancel' value='Cancel'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
    function testMe(){
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
                echo "alert('T E S T');\n";
                echo "</script>";
    }


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you cut out some of the "noisy" code? Just post the relevant stuff (i.e. the form that's being posted, and the php code that handles it).

Comment: You must call session_start(); before printing any echo, print or html code or you will get an error saying that the header are already sent ...

Comment: You need to do the debugging, and when you are stuck with a specific error, we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't ever close the `form` tag in the HTML, that might cause the page to not do anything when you click submit

Comment: hi. Thanks.. that was the problem, no </form> at the end of my script.. guys, sorry for the coding and for my english.. Im still a beginner in php. May I ask how or what is the right typing of codes? I mean what is the right format in coding?